# Show create value if not found in list angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a list. If the user did not find a value in this list using the search, it is necessary to show him the "create value" component. How do I compare the value from the search input with the values in the list? If there are no matches, then you need to show the "create value" component.

```
.create-value(
    '*ngIf'='searchQuery && isValuesMode && ["Dropdown", "Multiselect"].includes(selectedFieldType) && !searchValues.length'
    '[ngClass]'='{"active":!searchValues.length}'
    '(click)'='onQuickCreateFieldValue($event)'
)
    .text CREATE VALUE
    info-item
        .custom-icon('[ngStyle]'="{'background-color': DEFAULT_COLOR}")
        info-item-text.in-dropdown('[text]'='searchQuery')
dynamic-list(
    '*ngIf'="!isValuesMode || ['Person', 'Dropdown', 'Multiselect'].includes(selectedFieldType)"
    '[mode]'='selectedFieldType === "Multiselect" ? "multi" : "single"'
    '[options]'='isValuesMode ? searchValues : fields | fieldOptions : searchQuery'
    '[searchQuery]'='searchQuery'
    '[keydownEvents$]'='keydownEvents$'
    '[ngStyle]'='{"height": isWithSearch ? "240px" : "280px"}'
    '[optionTemplateRef]'='isValuesMode ? optionTemplateValues : optionTemplateList'
    '(action)'='onAction($event)'
    '(closeList)'='closeList.emit()'
)
```

```
onSearch(query: string): void {
        if (!this.isValuesMode) {
            this.search.emit(query);
        } else {
            if (query) {
                switch (this.selectedFieldType) {
                case 'Person':
                    this.searchValues = this.values.filter(elem => {
                        const name = this.teamMap[elem.title].firstName + ' ' + this.teamMap[elem.title].lastName;

                        return name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
                    });
                    break;
                case 'Dropdown':
                case 'Multiselect':
                    this.searchValues = this.values.filter(elem => elem.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
                    break;
                }
                this.cdRef.markForCheck();
            } else {
                this.searchValues = this.values;
                this.cdRef.markForCheck();
            }
        }
        this.searchQuery = query;
    }

onQuickCreateFieldValue(event: MouseEvent): void {
    
        const newValue = {
            title: this.searchQuery,
            properties: [
                {
                    name: 'sequence',
                    value: this.selectedField.values.length.toString()
                },
                {
                    name: 'color',
                    value: this.DEFAULT_COLOR
                }
            ]
        };

        this.quickCreateFieldValue.emit({value: newValue, selectedField: this.selectedField, projectId: this.entity.projectId});
    }
```

Comment: `How do I compare the value from the search input with the values in the list?` Assuming your list is an array, you could simply do `list.includes(searchValue)` as an example.

Comment: @MikeS. , what if the list is an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used method find. Now, if search value is not exist in array, I show create-value component.

TS:

```
            isSearchValueMode = false;
            
            if (this.values.find(elem => elem.title === this.searchQuery)){
                this.isSearchValueMode = false;
            }else{
                this.isSearchValueMode = true;
            }
```

HTML:

```
.create-value(
    '*ngIf'='searchQuery && isValuesMode && ["Dropdown", "Multiselect"].includes(selectedFieldType) && isSearchValueMode'
    '[ngClass]'='{"active":!searchValues.length}'
    '(click)'='onQuickCreateFieldValue($event)'
)
```